# 2010 Workflow for Sharepoint 2016 Double Booking?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, calendar

I am tasked to create an automated room booking calendar and my current issue
is double booking checks. I am trying to do this strictly through a Sharepoint Designer 2010 platform workflow.

People have been suggesting the reservation system but I do not feel like using a depreciated system. I also would rather not deal with code at the moment.

My biggest issue when trying to create a workflow is finding a way to access other event items in the same calendar as the current item you are working with.

Hope somebody can help,
thanks,
Colton

Comment: you've tagged your question with `sharepoint-online`, but your title says you are using SharePoint 2016 -- please correct one or the other.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your requirements? For example, what action do you use to access other items in the same calendar list? What do you mean “double booking checks”? You will need a specific property value to look up other list items in the workflow, like “All Day Event” = “Yes”.

Comment: that's just the issue, I don't know what action to take to access other items in the same list.

Comment: @colt.coogs There is no specific action to “access other items”, you need to use the look up control in an action to "Find the list item". The other items will have a known property value as a flag to be found.

Comment: @Chelsea_MSFT "The other items will have a known property value as a flag to be found". i understand that I need to do a lookup but what do you mean by this. Is there a unique value for each item that let's me differentiate them?

Comment: @colt.coogs I was referring to known property values of the list items, which is manually written by creators. Actually, there is one unique value for each item in one list – ID, which is automatically generated by SharePoint.